# How to default file saving to phone (not cloud)?

Tags: iphone, storage

I recently downloaded a lot of files to the "Files" folder app on my iPhone that came with it (not an app installed). Unfortunately, this caused all the files to be put on the "cloud", not on my phone as I expected, resulting in (among other problems) with me being unable to access those files when my phone is not connected.

How do I make Files store files on my phone, not the cloud by default? (Also, now that they are on the cloud, how do I move them onto the phone and off the "cloud"?)

I am using an iPhone 8 with iOS 16.

Please include step by step instructions. Pretend I'm stupid. Please don't just link generic instruction sites like the one from pcmag.com. They are old, useless and don't cover my use case. I need to get the files off the iCloud Drive and onto my local phone storage.

Comment: The "move" part you can do directly in the Files app. You should also be able to select "on my iPhone" when saving files, but this might depend on the actual way you download them.

Comment: See https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-use-the-files-app-on-iphone-ipad for details.

Comment: This is confusing.  Files (objects) are not downloaded to the Files app.  The app is used to *manage* files on the device, iCloud and other locations like OneDrive or SMB shares. What app specifically is defaulting to iCloud?

Comment: The PCMag article explains how the Files can be used to manage files on your iPhone, including moving data between different storage locations (which seems to be what you want to do).

Comment: But to clarify some grey areas mentioned in the answers below: How do you currently download data onto your phone? Wihtin Safari, within another browser, within another app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are downloading via Safari, it is possible to change the default destination as follows:

1. Open the **Settings** app
2. Scroll down and tap **Safari**
3. In the *General* section tap **Downloads**
4. Select **On My iPhone** to store downloads locally, or select **Other** to choose another more specific location

Note: I assume you are downloading files through your browser, as other apps on iOS often bring up a prompt that lets you pick the location manually.

---

As for moving existing files from the cloud to local storage:

1. Open the **Files** app:
2. Select the **Browse** tab on the bottom right
3. Starting under *Locations*, navigate to the files you wish to move
4. Tap the **three dots in a circle** on the top right
5. Choose **Select**
6. Select the files you wish to move
7. Tap and hold any of your selected files and do not let go until step 13
8. Once an options menu appears, drag your finger away until it is gone
9. Tap **Done** on the top right
10. If you have more files in other locations you wish to move:

    a. Navigate to them with another finger

    b. Repeat steps 2 to 6 and 9 while continuing to hold your selected files
11. Select the **Browse** tab on the bottom right
12. Navigate to where you wish the files to be
13. Release the finger with the files you have been holding since step 7, doing so anywhere except onto a folder icon (as that would copy the files to that folder instead)

Note: As of iOS 16.3.1 there is no way to *move* files between cloud and local storage - only *copy*. So you would need to delete files manually from the cloud to free up space.

Comment: This does not correspond with my experience. For example: I have a folder I want to move/copy from the icloud  to the phone. So, what happens is this: I go to Locations / iCloud Drive / navigate to directory / click three dots / Select / select folder by clicking on circle / hold down on folder / choose Download Now. If I then go to Locations / On My iPhone the selected folder is not present.

Comment: Nowhere in this post did I mention using Download Now. As per [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-ug/HT201104#offline), that option is for "download[ing] iCloud Drive files locally to work on while you're not connected to the internet" and "changes you make ... will automatically upload to iCloud Drive when you're back online" so it is essentially cached rather than saved to a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the iCloud folder:

1. Click on the 3 dots : [image: 3 dots]
2. Click on "Edit Sidebar" : [image: Edit Sidebar]
3. Disable the iCloud folder : [image: disable the iCloud folder]

This is for disabling the default file adding to iCloud.

How to move files from iCloud to your local iPhone storage (also works for iPad):

1. Click on the "Select" button : [image: "Select" button]
2. Click on "Move" : [image: "Move" button]
3. Click on "On My iPhone" : [image: "On My iPhone" button]
   And now, it's normally moved to your local storage.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: How does this answer the "need to get the files off the iCloud Drive and onto my local phone storage" part? Seems that disabling iCloud Drive will prevent this from being possible.

Comment: This answers the first part of the question, if you disable iCloud, it won't put files to iCloud by default. I will edit to answer the second part of the question.